# Passover Seder for the infirm. Leniencies?

Tags: time, passover-seder-hagada, choleh-sick, leniencies

These questions have already been asked of a Rav. The object of asking them here is to be better informed to understand the sources used by and the answers given by the Rav.

[1] I hope to make Sedorim for myself, my wife and someone who is infirm and cannot manage a seder of much longer than 30 mins. Possibly after 2 hours rest, the person may be able to be available for another 30 mins. 
Where is this subject discussed and what are the most important parts of the Seder to include?

[2] In London, on Seder night this year, nacht is around 9 pm. This could be late for an infirm person to start seder. Where are the sources that discuss whether any parts of the seder could be started before 9 pm, which parts and how early?

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, most of Shulchan Orekh can be skipped if pressed for time.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's also a useful leniency for people who struggle to eat sufficient matzah and maror.

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56333/759