# What is the minimum shiur for Shulchan Orekh?

Tags: halacha, passover-seder-hagada, shiurim-measurements

It [has been mentioned](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69271/passover-seder-for-the-infirm-leniencies#comment198389_69271) that abbreviating *shulchan orekh* at the *seder* can be a practical way of keeping the *seder* from going too late. I have also heard rabbis--when asked for leniencies in the amount of *matzah* and *maror* that must be eaten--exclaim, "you don't have room for a *kezayit* of *matzah* but you can eat three bowls of chicken soup?!" The obvious intention being, limit your consumption at the meal in order to fulfill your obligations for eating *matzah* and *maror*.

But is there a *minimum* for *shulchan orekh*? Since it's part of the *seder*, I imagine that it's not proper to skip it entirely. Is that true?  If so, what is the minimum *shiur* for *shulchan orekh*?  Is it measured in time, food consumed, or something else?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "part of the Seder". Many of the Rishonim don't mention a step for eating other food in their Seder-mnemonics. (I saw the title and thought this was PTIJ) These are just mnemonics to help people remember roughly what to do at this complicated and infrequent meal.

Comment: I'd think the same question can be asked about any _yom tov_. And I imagine it probably has the same answer.