# Minimum halachic requirements for Maggid section of seder?

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada

I will be leading the seder this year, and I know I'm running down to the last minute, but I want to know what are the paragraphs that I can skip, and what I absolutely need to do. It will be just my mom, my sister, and me, and none of us like to stay up late; at all. If I follow the "Bare Bones Basic Seder" from the "A Different Night" Haggadah, is that enough? Is there an outline that I can follow somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the minimum required sections of the Hagadah that must be said?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56333/what-are-the-minimum-required-sections-of-the-hagadah-that-must-be-said)

Comment: Hello 1998 tkhri, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your first question! It might get closed for having been asked before but please don't let this discourage yourself. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: @Scimonster while a truly complete answer to that question would answer this one, none of the them do. This does feel like a good follow up question to the other one though. This one asks what it takes to fulfill one of the items in the answers to the other question. That's different enough for me. For what that is worth.

Comment: @bst If the answers there are unsatisfactory, then consider starting a bounty, not asking a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Rav Modechai Kamenetzsky, Rabbi Avigdor Miller and others just read through the hagaddah with no embellishments or additions. That should be quick enough.

I checked the reference [CHECKLIST FOR YOUR PASSOVER](http://www.shamash.org/holidays/pesach/checklist.htm) The source has proven reliable in the past. You appear to be correct as to the reference to the hagaddah that you would want to use.

Here is the summary list for those who do not have that haggadah

> For those who would prefer "a Bare Bones Basic Seder" we can thank
>   Noam Zion for the following suggestion built into The Shalom Hartman
>   Institute Haggadah A Different Night. He suggests that sections 1-17
>   which take place before the meal should take about an hour. However,
>   it often occurs that once people "get into" a Seder, it can take
>   longer; don’t cut off the discussion and readings too early!
>
> Signposts of the Seder: Kadesh Urchatz
>   First Cup: Kiddush
>   Dips: Karpas
>   Breaking the Matza: Yachatz
>   The Story of the Matza: Ha Lachma
>   Four Questions: Ma Nishtana
>   Storytelling – "We were slaves": Avadeem Hayeenu
>   Four Children
>   The Promise: V’hee She-am-da
>   The Tale of the Wandering Jew
>   Ten Plagues
>   Dayeinu
>   Explaining Pesach, Matza and Maror
>   "In Every generation"
>   Psalm 114: Hallel
>   Second Cup of Wine
>   Eating Matza, Maror and Korech
>
> *After the Meal*
>   Afikoman
>   Blessing after eating: Barech
>   Third Cup of Wine
>   Elijah’s Cup and opening the door
>   Fourth Cup of Wine
>   Seder Songs traditional and new
>   Next Year in Jerusalem: La-Shana Haba-a
>
> **TRADITIONAL JEWISH LAW:** Legal Minimums of the Seder
>
> The following is taken from A Different Night, pp. 22-23 written by Noam Zion and David Dishon and published by The Shalom Hartman
>   Institute: "Reading every paragraph of the traditional Haggadah is not
>   legally obligatory. . . . The halachic minimum suggested below is an
>   invitation to add more, not to shorten the Seder. . . . In case of
>   doubt consult your rabbi. As we all know there are many views in
>   Jewish law. . . . We are grateful to Rabbi Yaacov Warhaftig, director
>   of the Ariel Institute, Orthodox Rabbinical Seminary in Jerusalem, who
>   gave us his advice and approval for this section."
>
> Candle-lighting
>   Optional: reading/chanting of poem Kadesh Urchatz
>   Kiddush and She-he-chee-yanu
>   Urchatz, Karpas, Yachatz
>   Ha Lachma Anya
>   Shmuel’s story:Avadeem Hayeenu
>   Optional: rabbis of B’nei Brak and Ben Zoma
>   Optional: but very important: the Midrash of the Four Children
>   Rav’s Story: Mee-Tchee-law, "Our Ancestors Were Idol Worshippers"
>   Optional but customary: V’hee She-amda
>   Arami Oved Avi: The obligation is to read and comment on this entire
>   section from Deuteronomy 26; but if the group has a creative
>   discussion on these verses rather than reading the entire midrash word
>   for word, this may be a wholly appropriate fulfillment of the mitzvah.
>
> Optional: Midrash on the 50, 200, 250 plagues
>   Optional and very traditional: Da-yeinu
>   Rabban Gamliel: Pesach, Matza, Maror
>   "In Every Generation" B’Chol Dor Va’Dor
>   Hallel, Psalms 113-114
>   Second Cup of Wine
>   Washing Hands and eating Matza with Maror, and then Korech
>   *Meal*
>   Afikoman
>   Birkat Ha-Mazone, "Grace After Meals"
>   Third Cup of Wine
>   Sh’foch Cha-mat-cha
>   Hallel and its Blessings
>   Fourth Cup of Wine and the Blessings after this cup of wine
>   Sefirat Ha-Omer is obligatory on the Second Seder Night
>   Optional but customary: Seder poems and songs
>   Optional but customary: Nirtza and "Next Year in Jerusalem"