# Seeking more seder skit ideas for kids

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, chinuch-education

Some [past posts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15278/beginners-seder-advice) have provided a few suggestions for skit topics for children at the seder (e.g., acting out the 10 plagues, acting out the exodus).  I am seeking additional seder skit ideas, both topics alone and actual role descriptions and dialogs.  (Indicate ages that the skits work for, if you know.)

Ideally, the skits would be from 1 to 10 minutes in length, would not require more than 15 minutes of preparation time before the seder, and would provide some connection with one or more of the main ideas or themes of seder.

Comment: Could you please [edit] this post to include objectively-evaluable criteria for what the idea response would be?

Comment: I don't see how this question differs from (a subset of) the one you link to. See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers

Comment: @msh210 As the title states, I seek additional ideas.  It is a timely topic.  People will see a recently posted question more easily than one four years old.

Comment: So you're saying it's a duplicate of the other? Great, then I'll redirect passersby thither.

Comment: See also the link in my earlier comment.

Comment: Yehuda the proper way to draw attention to an older post is to offer a bounty on it, not ask a duplicate. Please refrain from doing the latter in the future

Comment: @msh210 My question is not a dup of the other one.  The other one is more general. but received some answers that are relevant to my question. Pls remove the duplicate marking.

Comment: @DoubleAA My question is not a dup of the other one.  The other one is more general. but received some answers that are relevant to my question.